# PGFplotstable: using a csv file with 4 columns

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, csv

Suppose I have a csv file with no titles in it just data.  The first column is time (x axis) and the next 3 columns each construct a different set; that is, plot(t, col1) is one set of data, plot(t, col2), etc.

I can load the csv with the following command

```
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{data.csv}\mydata
```

How would I then plot each line?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.10}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{fexam1cdata.csv}\mydata
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    legend pos = south east,
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 20,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 2.5
    ]
    \addplot table[x = time, y = 2nd col]{\mydata};
    \addplot table[x = time, y = 3rd col]{\mydata};
    \addplot table[x = time, y = 4th col]{\mydata};
    \addplot table[x = time, y = 5th col]{\mydata};
    \legend{Actual, Measured, Est $Q = 0.01$, Est $Q = 0.1$}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Does `pgfplots` have an internal label name for each column?  Can I change it to time, actual, measured, Q1, Q2?

In the code above, I used `x = time` and `y = ith col` to show what I want where.  Those aren't correct and it wont compile since I don't know how to distinguish the columns in the csv file with `pgfplots`.

Comment: Would this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103179/34618

Comment: Do the `x index={0}, y index={1}`... options not work for you? Also, if the `x index` will be the same for each plot, you can set it in the `axis` options by adding `table/x index={0},` (I'm not sure if the `table/` is necessary, but I think it might be...)

Comment: @darthbith I am not saying something doesn't work.  I don't know how to change it.  So for the first plot data, I would have `x = {0}, y = {1}`?

Comment: No, `x index={0}, y index={0}`. I wasn't sure if you had seen that option in the manual and weren't able to use it for some reason :-) In the [pgfplots manual](http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf), version 1.10, its on page 49

Comment: @darthbith I was looking through the pgfplotstable manual

Comment: @dustin Ah ha. I wrote up my comment as an answer... hope it helps!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you do not have names for the columns in your csv file (i.e. in a header row) you can use the column indices, starting with zero to refer to them. See page 49 of version 1.10 of the [pgfplots manual](http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.10}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{fexam1cdata.csv}\mydata
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    legend pos = south east,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 20,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 2.5,
    ]
    \addplot table[x index = {0}, y index = {1}]{\mydata};
    \legend{Actual}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you'll be plotting multiple things with common options, you can specify the options in the `axis` options, like specifying the `x index`:

```
...
\begin{axis}[
    legend pos = south east,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 20,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 2.5,
    table/x index={0},
    ]
    \addplot table[y index={1}]{\mydata};
...
```

If you have any letter characters on the first row, you will also have to specify `header = false`, either when you load the table or in the axis options. This includes if you have `nan` in the first row.