# How do I plot descriptive stats from csv

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

My CSV looks like:

```
year,min,0.1,0.5,0.75,max,mean,totals
1992,4,200,400,780,1500,600,2345
1993,8,400,800,1560,3000,1200,4680
```

I'm after a box plot of this with pgfplots, however, the documentation is so large and I don't have the time to spend a few days working to even get a MWE. Could somebody provide an MWE I can work from?

If possible I'd also like to throw a trend line between the mean values of each plot too, and add a single integer value which I manually plot (i.e. not from CSV) to show an outlier.

Comment: Timmy, you can accept the answer if it solved the problem. This way, other people see that the answer helped you. The same is true for several of your other questions.

Comment: Done, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how the `total` column is needed for a boxplot but anyway, here's an adaptation of what you're asking based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/399171/204085), [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175309/pgfplotstable-using-a-csv-file-with-4-columns) and this [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459345/plot-bar-chart-from-csv-with-different-styles-depending-on-row-in-csv).

### Code

```latex
\documentclass[crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    boxplot prepared from table/.code={
        \def\tikz@plot@handler{\pgfplotsplothandlerboxplotprepared}%
        \pgfplotsset{
            /pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/.cd,
            #1,
        }
    },
    /pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/.cd,
        table/.code={\pgfplotstablecopy{#1}\to\boxplot@datatable},
        row/.initial=0,
        make style readable from table/.style={
            #1/.code={
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/row}}{##1}\of\boxplot@datatable
                \pgfplotsset{boxplot/#1/.expand once={\pgfplotsretval}}
            }
        },
        make style readable from table=lower whisker,
        make style readable from table=upper whisker,
        make style readable from table=lower quartile,
        make style readable from table=upper quartile,
        make style readable from table=median,
        make style readable from table=lower notch,
        make style readable from table=upper notch
}
\makeatother

\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{data.csv}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\TotalRows{\pgfplotsretval-1}

\begin{axis}[boxplot/draw direction=y,
xticklabels from table = {\datatable}{year},
xtick = {1,...,\TotalRows+1}
]

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\TotalRows}
{
    \addplot+[
    boxplot prepared from table={
        table=\datatable,
        row=#1,
        lower whisker=min,
        upper whisker=max,
        lower quartile=0.1,
        upper quartile=0.75,
        median=0.5
    },
    boxplot prepared]
    coordinates {};
};

\addplot table [x expr =\coordindex+1,y index=6] {\datatable};
\node[label={225:{Outlier}},circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt] at (axis cs:2,3000) {};
\legend{};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: LaTeX output]

Comment: The separator of of the CSV file? If so, comma, not single space.

Comment: `Cannot retrieve column 'year'  from table 'data.csv'`.

Comment: I just edited my answer to add the `[col sep = comma]` option to `\pgfplotstableread`.